# How can I repeat function to put another innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, return

I want to create div section in HTML after clicking something, but it happens just once and if I click again, it does nothing. Probably very base thing to know but I am just begginer.

```js
document.getElementById("plusvideo").onclick = function gkHaj() {
  var fdsf = 2;
  var text = document.getElementById("leftsidesd").innerHTML;
  var i = 1;
  if (fdsf == 2) {
    document.getElementById("leftsidesd").innerHTML = document.getElementById("leftsidesd").innerHTML + '<div class="episesnig">Episode 1 <input type="text" class="linkkepiz" placeholder="Link"></div>';
  } else {}
}
```

```html
<div id="leftsidesd">

  <div class="episernig">Series 01</div>
  <div id="plusvideo">+video</div>
  <div class="episesnig">Episode 1 <input type="text" class="linkkepiz" placeholder="Link"></div>

</div>
```

Well, there are things that are probably uselessly in this code but as I said, I click on plusvideo, than it works, than I click again and not working anymore, what code should I put there or what to do. Please help this pathetic begginer here :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of

`document.getElementById("leftsidesd").innerHTML = document.getElementById("leftsidesd").innerHTML + '<div class="episesnig">Episode 1 <input type="text" class="linkkepiz" placeholder="Link"></div>';`

The event listener attached to `plusvideo` is no more as the HTML is modified and old element is removed. So it doesn't work for more than once.

```js
var fdsf = 2;

document.getElementById("plusvideo").onclick = function gkHaj() {
  var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
  mydiv.setAttribute('class', 'episesnig');
  mydiv.innerHTML = 'Episode ' + fdsf + '<input type="text" class="linkkepiz" placeholder="Link">';
  fdsf++;
  document.getElementById("leftsidesd").appendChild(mydiv);
}
```

```html
<div id="leftsidesd">
  <div class="episernig">Series 01</div>
  <div id="plusvideo">+video</div>
  <div class="episesnig">Episode 1 <input type="text" class="linkkepiz" placeholder="Link"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
var i = 1;
            $('#plusvideo').click(function () {
                $('#leftsidesd').append('<div class="episesnig">Episode ' + i + ' <input type="text" class="linkkepiz" placeholder="Link"></div>')
                i++;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leftsidesd">

    <div class="episernig">Series 01</div><div id="plusvideo">+video</div>

</div>
```

:)

Comment: i'm curious to know that why OP code not working on second time click

Comment: I think because of changing DOM after adding new DIV